# Asp.NET Web-site without Internet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are planning to develop an ERP-project using ASP.NET and SQL. Client asked one feature: to be able to access and use ERP even if connection to Internet fails (using without Internet). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is, in a limited fashion. But the next question "how?" will be all too broad to answer on SO.

Comment: use it over lan, make virtual directory of the website and accesss it with local lan ip.

Comment: Without more information about your network topology and your setup a yes/no answer would be impossible. Try to include more detail in your question in order to get meaningful answers.

Comment: maybe html5 application cache can give you an idea as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use that without internet. You may host your web-site on some server in that company and all employers of that company may use this ERP. But nobody outside company will not be able to connect to that. Government committees usually use this way. If they scare about privacy and security, they may just take VPN access, it is secure. Another way (the worst, as I think): users from outside connect to computers inside company, and work over that computers.

Second solution: Web-based asynchronous application. You will create something like framework, you will install that to all users' computer. What is the principle of that's work? All user's will have their own database file, and they will work with their database. You just need to make a synchronization service between databases. For example, every time when user have internet, your service will synchronize data between user's database and server's database.